# Price column lost when converting timestamp column data to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm preparing my data for price analytics, so I created this code that pull the price feed from Coingecko API, sort the required columns, change the headers names and convert the date.

The current block I'm facing is once I convert the timestamp to datetime, I lose the price column, so how can I get it back along with the new date format?

```
import pandas as pd
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI

cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
response = cg.get_coin_market_chart_by_id(id='bitcoin',
                                            vs_currency='usd',
                                            days='90',
                                            interval='daily')
 
df1 = pd.json_normalize(response)

df2 = df1.explode('prices')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2['prices'].to_list(), columns=['dates','prices'])
df2 .rename(columns={'dates': 'ds','prices': 'y'}, inplace=True)
print('DATAFRAME EXPLODED: ',df2)

df2 = df2['ds'].mul(1e6).apply(pd.Timestamp)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2.to_list(), columns=['ds','y'])

df3 = df2.tail()
print('DATAFRAME TAILED: ',df3)
```

DATAFRAME EXPLODED:

```
         ds             y 

 0  1618185600000  59988.020959 
 1  1618272000000  59911.020595 
 2  1618358400000  63576.676041 
 3  1618444800000  62807.123233 
 4  1618531200000  63179.772446 
 ..            ...           ... 
 86 1625616000000  34149.989815 
 87 1625702400000  33932.254638 
 88 1625788800000  32933.578199 
 89 1625875200000  33971.297750 
 90 1625895274000  33738.909080

 [91 rows x 2 columns]
```

DATAFRAME TAILED:

```
86   2021-07-07 00:00:00 
87   2021-07-08 00:00:00 
88   2021-07-09 00:00:00 
89   2021-07-10 00:00:00 
90   2021-07-10 05:34:34 

Name: ds, type: datetime64[ns]
```

> `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (91, 1), indices imply (91, 3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change :

```
df2 = df2['ds'].mul(1e6).apply(pd.Timestamp)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2.to_list(), columns=['ds','y'])
```

to :

```
df2['ds_datetime'] = df2['ds'].mul(1e6).apply(pd.Timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI

cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
response = cg.get_coin_market_chart_by_id(id='bitcoin',
                                            vs_currency='usd',
                                            days='90',
                                            interval='daily')
 
df1 = pd.json_normalize(response)

df2 = df1.explode('prices')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2['prices'].to_list(), columns=['dates','prices'])
df2.rename(columns={'dates': 'ds','prices': 'y'}, inplace=True)
print('DATAFRAME EXPLODED: ',df2)

df2['ds'] = df2['ds'].mul(1e6).apply(pd.Timestamp)
# df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2.to_list(), columns=['ds','y'])

df3 = df2.tail()
print('DATAFRAME TAILED: ',df3)
```

By writing `df2 = df2['ds'].mul(1e6).apply(pd.Timestamp)`, you removed the price column from df2.

Comment: Thank you @jitesh , it works now, I need to exceed 15 reputations points to be able to mark your answer :(